# GLSL: "Invalid call of undeclared identifier 'texture2D'"

Tags: macos, opengl, glsl, opengl-3

I'm on a Mac, using Swift, and using OpenGL 3.2. I'm also using XCode 6.1 Beta so I suppose that's the most likely explanation, because it doesn't seem to me like this makes sense.

I can't find any evidence that this shouldn't be supported, but this fragment shader is resulting in the error `Invalid call of undeclared identifier 'texture2D'` during compilation:

```glsl
#version 150

uniform sampler2D usTexture;

in vec2 vTextureCoord;

out vec4 FragColor;

void main() {
  vec4 color = texture2D(usTexture, vTextureCoord);
  FragColor = color;
}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Cripes. Finally found the answer right after I posted the question. `texture2D` has been replaced by `texture`.

Comment: Yes, be aware that on OS X `#version 150` can only mean `#version 150 core`. On other platforms where compatibility profiles are implemented, you can continue to use things that were deprecated beginning in GLSL 1.30 such as `texture2D` if you write `#version 150 compatibility`. You really don't want that, but it's worth mentioning ;)

Comment: What about guys using #version 330. I'm using it and replacing 'texture2D' by 'texture' doesn't solve problem. What should I do?