# ERROR: 0:10: Invalid call of undeclared identifier 'texture2D'

Tags: macos, opengl, shader, fragment-shader

I'm using Mac and in OpenGL, I'm doing an assignment on texturing.

When I try to execute the file, I get a blank(black) window with this error message in my terminal:

```
Compile failure in the fragment shader:
ERROR: 0:10: Invalid call of undeclared identifier 'texture2D'
```

[image: image of terminal]

This is the code in my fragment shader file `06_fshader.glsl`:

```
#version 330


out vec4 frag_color;

uniform sampler2D texture;
in vec2 tex;
void main () 
{
      frag_color = texture2D(texture, tex);     
}
```

I know there is similar question here:[GLSL: "Invalid call of undeclared identifier 'texture2D'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26266198/glsl-invalid-call-of-undeclared-identifier-texture2d/26266341), but it didn't work for me.

Comment: What does it say when you change to `texture(...)` ?

Comment: It says this:

Compile failure in fragment shader:
ERROR: 0:10: Invalid call of 'texture' (not a function or subroutine uniform)

Comment: Yeah, that's because you called your uniform `texture` and now have a name conflict. Rename the uniform and it should work.

Comment: Rename uniform? the third line? What should I rename it to?

Comment: Doesn't matter which name you choose. As long as it is not texture. For example use `uniform texture2D mytexture;` and `... = texture(mytexture, tex)`. In short: never name variables with glsl method names.

Comment: Compile failure in fragment shader:
ERROR: 0:6: 'mytexture' : syntax error: syntax error

Comment: Hey resolved . `uniform sampler2D mytexture;` and `...... = texture(mytexture, tex)`

Comment: Sry. `uniform sampler2D mytexture`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with the code. The first one is, as explained in the linked question, that `texture2D` has been replace with `texture`.

The second problem is that there is already a uniform named `texture` which results in a naming conflict when trying to call `texture`(the method). This can be solved by renaming the uniform.

The final shader should look like this:

```
#version 330

out vec4 frag_color;

uniform sampler2D mytexture;
in vec2 tex;
void main () 
{
      frag_color = texture(mytexture, tex);     
}
```